# Converting Int to APInt in LLVM [C++]

Tags: c++, llvm

im trying to build language via LLVM (because i simply must), but was stuck at the simple start. Im trying to make int constants, but:

- ConstantInt::get method needs APInt class
- APInt class has no valid convertion from regular int to itself

this was my try:

```
Value * val = ConstantInt::get(Context, APInt(m_Lexer.numVal())
```

but answer is, that there is no APInt contructor accepting 32bit signed int.

My questions are simple:

- What im doing wrong or what is valid aproach?
- Where is some kind of documentation for LLVM c++ libraries, which isn't old and also got some comentaries?

I tryed worked by this tutorial, but it works only with doubles, but i need ints: https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl03.html

Comment: Uh, I use things like ConstantInt::get(i32, 0) all the time and have never needed APInt... check your source code again. get() has several overloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument to `ConstantInt::get` is an llvm `Type` not a `context`. Try this

```
Value * val = ConstantInt::get(Type::getInt32Ty(Context), m_Lexer.numVal(), true);
```

where the last boolean argument determines if `val` would represent a signed or unsigned `i32`